# Colorful Marshmallow

Tags: dessert, candy, color

How to make colorful marshmallow without using synthetic coloring agents?

Comment: Need more details please.  Presumably you are making your own marshmallow from scratch?  And you are referring to store-bought "food colouring" as "synthetic coloring agents?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are making your own marshmallows, you can add home made or purchased natural food color.  With home made colors there is a trade-off: too much coloring liquid and you get the added flavor, too little, and the colors will be whitish.  You make your own by [concentrating the juices](http://www.buzzle.com/articles/natural-food-coloring.html) of blueberries, raspberries, spinach, or carrots, or by using turmeric.

If you live close to a Whole Foods supermarket (or other well supplied supermarket) look in the spice section for the India Tree natural dyes. They cost more than the artificial colors, but they save you a lot of work.  You may also [buy them online](http://www.naturalcandystore.com/product/natural-decorating-food-colors).

There are several companies that make natural colors.  US based [Wild Flavors](http://www.wildflavors.com/?page=colors) explains on their web site how they produce the natural colors they sell (look for the [PDFs](http://www.wildflavors.com/?fuseaction=home.download&folder_file_id=38CE8CBE-CF1C-2465-177E12A3EFBB4719) in the color library).

Answer (score 8):

Small amounts of natural fruit or vegetable juices should provide some colour without altering the flavour too much.

If you have access to a juicer, carrot, beet, strawberry and blueberry all come to mind as colouring agents.